# How to add objects to an array in React and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a form that takes an order from customers and I am using React Redux to manage my state. There is an array of object named items where I add the items of the order to it. Every item is an object of 4 properties (name, quantity, price, instructions). And here is how I handle my form :

```
for (let i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++) {
        rows.push(
            <div key={i} className="add-items-form">
                <div className="items-header-container">
                    <h3 className="items-form-header">ITEM #{i + 1}</h3>
                    <Button onClick={() => removeItem(i)}>Remove Item</Button>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
                        <Label >Item Name</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="name" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.items.name} />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
                        <Label >QTY</Label>
                        <Input type="number" name="quantity" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.items.quantity} />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
                        <Label >Price</Label>
                        <Input type="number" name="price" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.items.price} />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
                        <Label >Special Instructions</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="special_instructions" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.items.special_instructions} />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    };
```

This is the redux action that takes the input :

```
export function setFormValue(field) {
    console.log("FIELD", field.target.value)
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: types.SET_FORM_VALUE, payload: field })
    };
}
```

This is my reducer function where I am handling the part of the items in the form:

```
 if (action.payload.target.name === "items") {
                let cloneditems = [...state.form.items];
                cloneditems.push(action.payload.target.value);
                return {
                    ...state,
                    form: {
                        ...state.form,
                        items: cloneditems
                    }
                };
            }
```

What I am planning to do is to add an item object and push it to the items array every time I add an item with its details in my form. Yet, it adds them outside the items array not inside it as an object. Can anyone help me with this part as it consumes a lot of time and I cannot make it? Here is a link to my project if you want to have a look :

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-williamson-nvqx9?file=/src/redux/reducer.js

and here is an example of what I am planning to get :

```
form : {
     user :[{
          name: "",
          quantity:"",
          price:"",
          instructions:""
     }]
}
```

Moreover, this is my reducer initial state :

```
const initialState = {
    form: {
        pickup_address: {},
        delivery_address: {},
        items: [{
            index: 0,
            name: "",
            quantity: 0,
            price: 0,
            special_instructions: ""
        }]
    },
    numOfItems: 0,
};
```

Any help ?!

Comment: I'll give this an upvote as this was quite wierd to solve, share the for loop as well.. and i would delete your previous question to avoid getting downvoted.

Comment: share the reducer initial state as well.

Comment: @BARNOWL Thanks a million bro. If you have time, would you pls take a look at that form again as your first fix doesn't work with it.

Comment: Can't im sorry. Someone else can possibly help as this isn't a simple fix. there are issues with your code. If i were you i would definitely look into the react docs like this https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html :) all the best.

Comment: @BARNOWL ok fine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if post CodeSandbox link,

I just posted simple way to add objects to an array, Maybe helpful.

```js
var myArray = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"];
myArray.push("Yellow");

var myObject = {id: 1, name: "Amoos", class: 10}; 

myArray.push(myObject);

console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Here you are : https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-williamson-nvqx9?file=/src/redux/reducer.js

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-haze-5p346?file=/src/forms/itemForm.js

Try it now

itemDetails

```
for (let i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++) {
    rows.push(
      <ItemForm
        index={i}
        removeItem={removeItem}
        setItemName={setItemName}
        setQuantity={setQuantity}
        setPrice={setPrice}
        setInstructions={setInstructions}
        itemName={name}
        qty={quantity}
        price={price}
        special_instructions={special_instructions}
      />
      // <div key={i} className="add-items-form">
      //   <div className="items-header-container">
      //     <h3 className="items-form-header">ITEM #{i + 1}</h3>
      //     <Button onClick={() => removeItem(i)}>Remove Item</Button>
      //   </div>
      //   <div className="row">
      //     <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
      //       <Label>Item Name</Label>
      //       <Input
      //         type="text"
      //         name="name"
      //         onChange={e => setItemName(e.target.value)}
      //         value={itemName}
      //       />
      //     </FormGroup>
      //     <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
      //       <Label>QTY</Label>
      //       <Input
      //         type="text"
      //         name="quantity"
      //         onChange={e => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
      //         value={qty}
      //       />
      //     </FormGroup>
      //   </div>
      //   <div className="row">
      //     <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
      //       <Label>Price</Label>
      //       <Input
      //         type="text"
      //         name="price"
      //         onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)}
      //         value={price}
      //       />
      //     </FormGroup>
      //     <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
      //       <Label>Special Instructions</Label>
      //       <Input
      //         type="text"
      //         name="special_instructions"
      //         onChange={e => setInstructions(e.target.value)}
      //         value={instructions}
      //       />
      //     </FormGroup>
      //   </div>
      // </div>
    );
  }
```

**itemForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, FormGroup, Input, Label } from "reactstrap";
function ItemForm(props) {
  console.log("dssd", props.price);
  return (
    <div key={props.index} className="add-items-form">
      <div className="items-header-container">
        <h3 className="items-form-header">ITEM #{props.index + 1}</h3>
        <Button onClick={() => props.removeItem(props.index)}>
          Remove Item
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
          <Label>Item Name</Label>
          <Input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            onChange={e => props.setItemName(e.target.value)}
            value={props.name}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
          <Label>QTY</Label>
          <Input
            type="text"
            name="quantity"
            onChange={e => props.setQuantity(e.target.value)}
            value={props.quantity}
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
          <Label>Price</Label>
          <Input
            type="text"
            name="price"
            onChange={e => props.setPrice(e.target.value)}
            value={props.price}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
          <Label>Special Instructions</Label>
          <Input
            type="text"
            name="special_instructions"
            onChange={e => props.setInstructions(e.target.value)}
            value={props.instructions}
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ItemForm;
```